# I want when Click button in android studio make connection with python

Tags: android, python, ipython

I tried clicking on a button to make connection with python
but it doesn't run except it only run in main

This is the code that run the connection

```
public class link {

    public static void main(String a[]) {
        try {
            Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(
                "python C:/Users/ASUS/Desktop/sendingCode/jaad/app/test.py");
            Scanner in = new Scanner(new InputStreamReader(
                p.getInputStream()));
            String line = "";
            while ((line = in.nextLine()) != null) {
                // display each output line form python script
                System.out.println(line);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

Once I put the previous code on button it wont work with me i dont know why

```
recordBtn=(Button)findViewById(R.id.recordBtn);
recordBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        try {
            Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(
                        "python C:/Users/ASUS/Desktop/sendingCode/jaad/app/test.py");
            Scanner in = new Scanner(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
            String line = "";
            while ((line = in.nextLine()) != null) {
                // display each output line form python script
                System.out.println(line);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: So that code runs on your pc. But not on your app on an Android device far away from your pc. Is that what you are telling us?

Comment: I want when Click button in android studio. You mean in an Android app on a Android device?

Comment: it is not run on all app & device

Comment: Sorry, what did you say?